# Teams API button action

Tags: api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use teams API for sending alerts to users and perform actions according to their feedbacks.

So far I was able to open a chat with the user and send an Adaptive Card message with buttons that do nothing.

I will be happy to understand how can make the button clicked trigger running of a script.

Below is my buttons data:

```
    "buttons": [
        {
            "type": "messageBack",
            "title": "Yes",
            "text": "login",
            "displayText": "login",
            "value": "login"
        },
        {
            "type": "messageBack",
            "title": "No",
            "text": "login",
            "displayText": "login",
            "value": "login"
        },
```

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Which API do you mean? Graph API?

Comment: Yes, meant Graph API

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to understand, that this way of sending messages via Graph is only one option, and it's great for text, or cards without actions. However, if you need a response from the user, the problem here is that there is nothing listening on the other end when that action is invoked. If you need to receive a response, the best option might be to write a proper Bot instead of using Graph (something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot)).

Comment: stumble upon this message. that is not entirely true, you could also subscribe to a chat with a webhook so that you can receive message sent by the user in that chat.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-with-resource-data

Comment: True - I should have clarified when I said "best option". Change notifications are complicated for several reasons, compared with the bot approach, but as in many things "it depends".